# Could one write an Android app in pure Go using no Java or XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, go

Could you write an android app in 100% Go or would you have to use some Java and XML too?

Answer (score 2):

From [Go Blog](http://blog.golang.org/)

> When will Go be a first-class language for Android development?
>
> Andrew: This would be great, but we don't have anything to announce.

If you are looking further, there is a good explanation on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Google-support-the-Go-programming-language-for-Android-development)